# How can I fix this Random and Pygame library error?

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to make a "Who Wants to be a millionaire?" type game, and I want to test it out via a thing where if I press down the left mouse button, and random number generator generates a number from a list and it draws the code on the screen that belongs to the number and removes that number.

Now, the problem is that I tried it literally every single way, but it keeps appearing more than twice. The code under now is trying to say that if we are out of the numbers, then change the screen to black. Now, this is not working, it gives an error like this:

```
none
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\joemama\Farsang\Kérdések\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    result = random.choice(number)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 346, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
1
```

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import os
import random

WIDTH, HEIGHT = (1024, 768)
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Joe mama")
kerdes1 = pygame.image.load("Zene/1/Kérdés-1.png")
kerdes2 = pygame.image.load("Zene/2/Kérdés-2.png")

number = [1, 2]
numbers = 2

def number_one():
    WIN.blit(kerdes1, (0, 0))

def number_two():
    WIN.blit(kerdes2, (0, 0))

while True:
    result = random.choice(number)
    if len(number) == 0:
        break
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                if result == 1:
                    print("1")
                    number.remove(1)
                    numbers -= 1
                    number_one()
                    if numbers == 0:
                        WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
                        break
                elif result == 2:
                    print("2")
                    number.remove(2)
                    numbers -= 1
                    number_two()
                    if numbers == 0:
                        WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
                        break
                pygame.display.update()
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You need to put the check for `len(number) == 0` *before* you call `random.choice(number)`

Comment: `result = random.choice(number)` You are removing stuff from `number` so when it becomes an empty list you get `IndexError`.

Comment: You could just use `while len(number) > 0:`

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't give me an error, but it immediately closes the window after I press the left click again

Comment: Add some more print statements to see what's happening.

Comment: @Barmar to what places?

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: before every `if` to see the value of the variable you're testing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure which behavior you want to have in the end, but how about this one?

First, you change this part of code right after the `while True:` from

```
result = random.choice(number)
if len(number) == 0:
    break
```

to

```
if len(number) > 0:
    result = random.choice(number)
```

In this way, you will only choose a number if there is still one left in the list.

---

After that you also change the code below the if statement where you test for `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if event.button == 1:
        if len(number) == 0:
            WIN.fill((0, 0, 0))
        else:
            if result == 1:
                print("1")
                number.remove(1)
                numbers -= 1
                number_one()

            elif result == 2:
                print("2")
                number.remove(2)
                numbers -= 1
                number_two()

        pygame.display.update()
```

Now, when you press the mousebutton and there is no number left to choose from, you fill the screen with a solid black. I also deleted the break statements you had in there, because when you fill the screen black and break afterwards, the game will end immediately and you cannot see the change.